# get var from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, nsarray, nsdictionary

Using that code I'm able to get all the list of array.

Looking a lot of tutorial but I'm not able to get the var called "id" if the "name" isEqual to "Timeline Photos".

**Code:**

```
     NSArray *feed =[result objectForKey:@"data"];
      for (NSDictionary *dict in feed) {

            NSLog(@"%@",dict);                                  
 }
```

**Result (Example of the first two result):**

```
2015-02-03 13:59:21.246 Project[708:29363] {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    count = 68;
    "cover_photo" = 10200808394440000;
    "created_time" = "2011-03-09T17:25:03+0000";
    from =     {
        id = 10204248513160000;
        name = "XX XX";
    };
    id = 1716972770000;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?..";
    name = "Mobile Uploads";
    privacy = everyone;
    type = mobile;
    "updated_time" = "2015-01-31T13:28:32+0000";
}
2015-02-03 13:59:21.247 Project[708:29363] {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    count = 11;
    "cover_photo" = 4383404270000;
    "created_time" = "2010-02-15T15:50:30+0000";
    from =     {
        id = 10204248513160000;
        name = "XX XX";
    };
    id = 1267183610000;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?...";
    name = "Timeline Photos";
    privacy = everyone;
    type = wall;
    "updated_time" = "2015-01-28T18:26:52+0000";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 NSArray *feed =[result objectForKey:@"data"];
  for (NSDictionary *dict in feed) {

        if ([dict[@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Timeline Photos"])
            NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"id"]);                                  
}
```

This will only print `id` when `name` is equal to Timeline Photos.
Actually, you are not working with an array, but with a dictionary.

Hope this helps.